# How to collect DBT JOB run history information using the API call?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

curious to know if anyone is aware of using the API to collect DBT all JOB run history information. I want to collect all the history of failed DBT jobs for a particular period.

Answer (score 0):

There is one file `run_results.json` generated during each run under folder `/target/run_results.json`. Parse it and get both success or error result for each model.

We can save the `/target/run_results.json` after each run as history. Use it for further processing for statistics specially for production environment.

Here is an example of error result one model.

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "timing": [
        {
            "name": "compile",
            "started_at": "2024-02-26T08:51:13.498834Z",
            "completed_at": "2024-02-26T08:51:13.503655Z"
        },
        {
            "name": "execute",
            "started_at": "2024-02-26T08:51:13.504814Z",
            "completed_at": "2024-02-26T08:51:13.521167Z"
        }
    ],
    "thread_id": "Thread-1 (worker)",
    "execution_time": 0.03046393394470215,
    "adapter_response": {},
    "message": "Runtime Error in model construtor_drivers_championships (models/stats/construtor_drivers_championships.sql)\n  Binder Error: Contents of view were altered: names don't match!",
    "failures": null,
    "unique_id": "model.F1.construtor_drivers_championships",
    "compiled": true,
    "compiled_code": "with\n    driver_points as (\n        select\n            constructors.constructor_name,\n            max(driver_standings.points) as max_points,\n            races.race_year as race_year\n        from \"data\".\"main\".\"stg_f1_dataset__constructors\" constructors\n        join\n            \"data\".\"main\".\"stg_f1_dataset__results\" results\n            on constructors.constructor_id = results.constructor_id\n        join \"data\".\"main\".\"stg_f1_dataset__races\" races on results.race_id = races.race_id\n        join\n            \"data\".\"main\".\"stg_f1_dataset__driver_standings\" driver_standings\n            on driver_standings.race_id = races.race_id\n            and driver_standings.driver_id = results.driver_id\n        group by constructors.constructor_name, races.race_year\n    ),\n    constructor_driver_championships as (\n        select\n            *, rank() over (partition by race_year order by max_points desc) as r_rank\n        from driver_points\n        where race_year != EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)\n    )\n\nselect constructor_name, count(constructor_name) as total_driver_championships\nfrom constructor_driver_championships\nwhere r_rank = 1\ngroup by constructor_name",
    "relation_name": "\"data\".\"main\".\"construtor_drivers_championships\""
},
```

Comment: Thanks Rockie, I will deploy this and update you if any challenges face...